# TikZ: How to draw a node that is a circle with a centered dot?

Tags: tikz-styles

For a diagram I'm trying to build a tree, nodes are circles. I need some of the nodes marked with a centered dot (something like `textbullet` in the center of the node). An image that I'd like to duplicate is:

[image: tree diagram]

My tree up to now is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance = 2cm,
                  level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 1cm}]
    \node[circle,draw]{}
      child{ node[circle, draw]{}
        child{ node[circle, draw]{}
        child{ node[circle, draw]{}}
        child{ node[circle, draw]{}}
      }
      child{ node[circle, draw]{}}
      child{ node[circle, draw]{}}
    }
    child{ node[circle, draw]{}
      child{ node[circle, draw]{}
        child{ node[circle, draw]{}}
        child{ node[circle, draw]{}}
      }
    };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{A tree}
 \label{fig:tree}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Three out of many options.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cc1/.style={circle,draw,node contents={\textbullet}},
cc2/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1cm,path picture={
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=2mm];},node contents={}}]
\path (0,0) node[circle,draw]{\textbullet} 
 (1,0) node[cc1] (2,0) node[cc2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When the outer circle is small, the `\textbullet` is too high (not centered), it looks funny. Learned some Ti*k*Z today, thanks! A long road ahead...

Comment: @vonbrand You can center it but one thing that always works without additional keys is the `path picture`.

Answer (score 3):

#### New answer

You can simplify the code by simply writing  `child` instead of `child{ node[circle, draw]{}}` and creating a style that applies to all childs:

```
every child node/.style={circle,draw,node contents=\textbullet}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance = 2cm,
                  level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 1cm},
                  every child node/.style={circle,draw,anchor=center,node contents=\textbullet}]
    \node[circle,draw]{\textbullet}
      child{ 
        child{ 
        child
        child
      }
      child
      child
    }
    child{ 
      child{ 
        child
        child
      }
    };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{A tree}
 \label{fig:tree}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

Like this ?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=center,draw,circle] at (0,0) {\textbullet};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understood, that OP looking for tree, which nodes are circle. Some of nodes has bullet inside ... however, without any code (MWE) is difficult to say anything.

Comment: Indeed, we'll see...

Comment: See the image. Not all nodes should be the same. Again, thanks. Learned another bit...

Comment: Also, if you look the bullet is slightly off-center (a bit high). For large circles it doesn't matter, but mine should be small...

Comment: @vonbrand I forgot to anchor the knots in the center. I just updated my answer. It looks like it's centered now.

Comment: @vonbrand If it's not well centered, try with `anchor=base` orànchor=mid` I don't have good enough eyesight to tell if the centering is perfect or not. :-(